# node-gyp platform specific addon

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon, platform-specific

Is it possible to specify that a certain native addon is only meant to be build for a certain platform (e.g: `win32`)?

Currently I have a C++ addon that makes use of the Windows API, but `node-gyp` attempts to build that for UNIX based systems as well.

I've been searching in [node-gyp documentation](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and [NodeJS C/C++ addon documentation section](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) without any luck.

Comment: What would the expect behavior of the module be if it fails to build? One example that comes to mind is [`bson`](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/c91d5e89910f0bac15554e6ff3a7d157a1d44d56/package.json#L25) which overrides the 'install' script to always return success even if the build fails. Then in JS, it falls back to a JS implementation when the binary is not available.

Comment: @loganfsmyth If the native module fails to build, then my module shouldn't   be installed, as the behavior implemented by the native module is essential to the module, as I can't be implemented in JavaScript as a fallback.

Comment: Then you can declare the module in `optionalDependencies` instead of `dependencies` in `package.json`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth The native addon doesn't live in a separate module. It's sources and the `bindings.gyp` live within my project, and I want to instruct `node-gyp` to only build the addon for win32. Is this possible? Another alternative, like you mention would be to move the native addon to another module, put it as an optional dependency in my main project and do a conditional `require` if `win32`, however I'd like to avoid splitting the modules.

Comment: In the future, please try to include as many details as possible in the question. Everything in these comments are great, but having them included from the start would have helped a lot.

Comment: @jviotti, did you found an answer so this. I am also caught up the in the exactly problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You can add an `"os"` section to your `package.json` to restrict which platforms your addon is compatible with.

Here is the [OS package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#os) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own installation script that checks the platform and conditionally builds the binary based on platform.

For example, [`js-bson`](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/c91d5e89910f0bac15554e6ff3a7d157a1d44d56/package.json#L25) includes a custom script the attempt to build and fail silently. You could instead include a script in there that checks the OS, and only runs `node-gyp rebuild` if the system is windows.